# Does mirror symmetry require large complex structure limit points?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, mirror-symmetry

I would like to understand mirror symmetry, so I have been reading books such as *"Mirror symmetry and algebraic geometry"* and *"Calabi-Yau manifolds and related geometries"*. In these books, the mirror conjecture is formulated using large complex structure limit points. When consulting less detailed sources such as wikipedia, no mention is made of this. The conjecture will typically be stated along the lines of "every Calabi-Yau threefold has a mirror", irrespective of the complex structure on said threefold.

I would like to know whether these less detailed sources are omitting technicalities for simplicity, or whether the LCSL points are just a computational tool - or some other explanation for why the statements do not coincide.